# Html.RenderAction error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC 1 application and using Visual Web Developer Express. I can not get the Html.RenderAction("Controller","Action") to work on my MasterPage. (Site.Master) in the Shared folder.

VWD says "Html" is not recognized here.

I took to the following steps to implement the Html.RenderAction("Controller","Action") method.

1. Downloaded Micrsoft.Web.Mvc.dll
2. Updated the web.config with a reference to Micrsoft.Web.Mvc.dll '
3. I added a reference to Micrsoft.Web.Mvc.dll in my project manually.

I'm following the book: Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework by Steven Sanderson and downloaded the sample file where he covers this topic (Ch 4 - 6) and his sample file is giving me the same error?

Please help!

Thanks!
Quinntyne

Comment: What version of VWD are you using?

Comment: <% Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account") %>; Works in my Article view, but not on the MasterPage?

Answer (score 2):

Sample code would help.

A few things:

1. Html.RenderAction() is not available in MVC 1, it was added in MVC 2.  That's probably not the cause of your error message though.
2. When you say that you "added a reference in your web.config,", make sure you added the namespaces to the namespaces section:

   ```
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
   ```

Adding that last one will probably address the issue.

Comment: Here is the namespace section of my web.config:

<namespaces>
 <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
 <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
 <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
 <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
 <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
 <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="QuinntyneBrown.HtmlHelpers"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>
</namespaces>

Comment: <% Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account") %>; Works in the a View, but not the MasterPage?

Comment: Does your master page inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage?